# How to create custom config section in app.config?

Tags: c#, app-config

I want to add a custom configuration section in my `app.config` file.
Is there a way to do it and how can I access these settings in my program.
Following is the config section I want to add to my `app.config`:

```
<RegisterCompanies>
    <Companies>
      <Company name="Tata Motors" code="Tata"/>
      <Company name="Honda Motors" code="Honda"/>
    </Companies>
</RegisterCompanies>
```

Answer (score 156, accepted):

Import namespace :

```
using System.Configuration;
```

Create ConfigurationElement Company :

```
public class Company : ConfigurationElement
{

        [ConfigurationProperty("name", IsRequired = true)]
        public string Name
        {
            get
            {
                return this["name"] as string;
            }
        }
            [ConfigurationProperty("code", IsRequired = true)]
        public string Code
        {
            get
            {
                return this["code"] as string;
            }
        }
}
```

ConfigurationElementCollection:

```
public class Companies
        : ConfigurationElementCollection
    {
        public Company this[int index]
        {
            get
            {
                return base.BaseGet(index) as Company ;
            }
            set
            {
                if (base.BaseGet(index) != null)
                {
                    base.BaseRemoveAt(index);
                }
                this.BaseAdd(index, value);
            }
        }

       public new Company this[string responseString]
       {
            get { return (Company) BaseGet(responseString); }
            set
            {
                if(BaseGet(responseString) != null)
                {
                    BaseRemoveAt(BaseIndexOf(BaseGet(responseString)));
                }
                BaseAdd(value);
            }
        }

        protected override System.Configuration.ConfigurationElement CreateNewElement()
        {
            return new Company();
        }

        protected override object GetElementKey(System.Configuration.ConfigurationElement element)
        {
            return ((Company)element).Name;
        }
    }
```

and ConfigurationSection:

```
public class RegisterCompaniesConfig
        : ConfigurationSection
    {

        public static RegisterCompaniesConfig GetConfig()
        {
            return (RegisterCompaniesConfig)System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.GetSection("RegisterCompanies") ?? new RegisterCompaniesConfig();
        }

        [System.Configuration.ConfigurationProperty("Companies")]
            [ConfigurationCollection(typeof(Companies), AddItemName = "Company")]
        public Companies Companies
        {
            get
            {
                object o = this["Companies"];
                return o as Companies;
            }
        }

    }
```

and you must also register your new configuration section in web.config (app.config):

```
<configuration>       
    <configSections>
          <section name="Companies" type="blablaNameSpace.RegisterCompaniesConfig, blablaAssemblyName" ..>
```

then you load your config with

```
var config = RegisterCompaniesConfig.GetConfig();
foreach(var item in config.Companies)
{
   do something ..
}
```

Comment: Its worth noting that if you are using an MVC app, then the section listed is fine.  With a console app, Web Service, and perhaps others, you need to have ', AssemblyName' after 'blablabla.RegisterCompaniesConfig'

Comment: Need to specify the assembly in the type attribute of the section tag

Comment: I'm getting the exception "does not inherit from 'System.Configuration.IConfigurationSectionHandler" .. what am I doing wrong ?

Comment: Thank you @ilmatte. i missed out the assemble name

Comment: Never ceases to amaze me how often Stackoverflow ranks higher than the [vendor's own documentation site](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2tw134k3.aspx) itself :)

Comment: Guess I should've qualified my previous comment with the keywords I was actually using: `writing customconfig section c#`

Comment: @KevinDeus can you show an example?

Comment: Also worth noting for the uninitiated,  <configSections> NEEDS to be the first child of <configuration>

Comment: more details on the config file xml schema can be found [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/configure-apps/file-schema/section-element)

Comment: Make ConfigurationElementCollection Type-Explicit: https://www.codeproject.com/Tips/1037705/Make-Your-ConfigurationElementCollection-Type-Expl

Comment: It would be overkill for the original example, but Kreol is onto something that could be used for others with complex config files. I had done this before with nested collection classes, collection classes with indexers, typed item classes,  typed values i.e. string, int, enum values, etc. You can basically make your config anyway you want and provide typed results when you go to retrieve it. But it can take a bit of effort at times.