# App.config Nested custom handler required in c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, nested, app-config

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to create custom config section in app.config?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1316058/how-to-create-custom-config-section-in-app-config)

I am struggling to read custom sections from my app.config file. Could some one help me in this. I have a nested custom section in app.config up to 6 levels.

My App.config

```
<configuration>
   <Parent>
       <mySystem>
           <mySystemContainers>
               <mySystemContainer name="one" >
                    <mySystems> 
                        <clear/>
                            <System Name="name" GroupName="Group1"/>
                            <System Name="name2" GroupName="Group1"/> 
                     </mySystems>
              </mySystemContainer> 
        </mySystem> 
     </Parent>
 </configuration>
```

Comment: Got anything more to go on, config example, code etc?

Comment: put your custome section and the code which your are trying.

Comment: App.config sections are below<configuration><Parent><mySystem><mySystemContainers><mySystemContainer name="one" ><mySystems> <clear/><System Name="name" GroupName="Group1"/><System Name="name2" GroupName="Group1"/> </mySystems></mySystemContainer>
</mySystem> </Parent></configuration>

Comment: Put that in your question.  It's impossible to read in a comment, as you can see.