# Customized IEnumerable in ConfigurationSection

Tags: c#, configuration, app-config

I need to create a simple customized ConfigurationSection with an IEnumerable inside it.

I have read several articles and stackoverflow links, taking this as a simple example:
[How to create custom config section in app.config?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1316058/how-to-create-custom-config-section-in-app-config)

So, I have this config file section inside a Console App:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <section name="Disk"
             type="ConsoleApplication1_ConfigurationEnumerable.PathsConfigSection"/>
  </configSections>
  <Disk>
    <Paths>
      <Path name="one" permission="1" />
      <Path name="two" permission="2" />
      <Path name="three" permission="3" />
    </Paths>
  </Disk>
</configuration>
```

Next I have this whole structure to manage the config section:
    using System.Configuration;

```
namespace ConsoleApplication1_ConfigurationEnumerable
{
    public class Path: ConfigurationElement
    {
        [ConfigurationProperty("name", IsRequired = true)]
        public string Name
        {
            get
            {
                return (string)this["name"];
            }
        }

        [ConfigurationProperty("permission", IsRequired=true)]
        public string Permission
        {
            get
            {
                return (string)this["permission"];
            }
        }
    }    

    public class Paths: ConfigurationElementCollection 
    {
        public Path this[int index] 
        {
            get
            {
                return base.BaseGet(index) as Path;
            }
            set 
            {
                if (base.BaseGet(index) != null) {
                    base.BaseRemoveAt(index);
                }
                this.BaseAdd(index, value);
            }
        }

        protected override ConfigurationElement CreateNewElement() 
        {
            return new Path();
        }
        protected override object  GetElementKey(ConfigurationElement element)
        {
            return ((Path)element).Name;
        }
    }

    public class PathsConfigSection : ConfigurationSection
    {
        public static PathsConfigSection GetConfig()
        {
            //return (PathsConfigSection)System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.GetSection("Disk") ?? new PathsConfigSection();
            return (PathsConfigSection)System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.GetSection("Paths") ?? new PathsConfigSection();
        }

        [ConfigurationProperty("Paths")]
        public Paths Paths
        {
            get 
            {
                object o = this["Paths"];
                return o as Paths;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And here the program.cs using the whole thing:
using System;

```
namespace ConsoleApplication1_ConfigurationEnumerable
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var config = PathsConfigSection.GetConfig();
            if (config == null || config.Paths.Count == 0)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Is null or empty");
            }
            else
            {
                foreach (Path item in config.Paths)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Item {0} with valuer {1}", item.Name, item.Permission);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The problem here is inside this two lines:

```
//return (PathsConfigSection)System.Configuration
//       .ConfigurationManager.GetSection("Disk") ?? new PathsConfigSection();
return (PathsConfigSection)System.Configuration
       .ConfigurationManager.GetSection("Paths") ?? new PathsConfigSection();
```

If I use the second one (uncommented above) it returns null.

If I use the commented one, then it throws an exception like this:

> System.Configuration.ConfigurationErrorsException was unhandled
>   HResult=-2146232062   Message=An error occurred creating the
>   configuration section handler for Disk: Could not load type
>   'ConsoleApplication1_ConfigurationEnumerable.PathsConfigSection' from
>   assembly 'System.Configuration, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'.
>   (C:\Users\blackberry\Desktop\ConsoleApplication1_ConfigurationEnumerable\ConsoleApplication1_ConfigurationEnumerable\bin\Debug\ConsoleApplication1_ConfigurationEnumerable.vshost.exe.config
>   line 4)   Source=System.Configuration   BareMessage=An error occurred
>   creating the configuration section handler for Disk: Could not load
>   type 'ConsoleApplication1_ConfigurationEnumerable.PathsConfigSection'
>   from assembly 'System.Configuration, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'.
>   Filename=C:\Users\blackberry\Desktop\ConsoleApplication1_ConfigurationEnumerable\ConsoleApplication1_ConfigurationEnumerable\bin\Debug\ConsoleApplication1_ConfigurationEnumerable.vshost.exe.config
>   Line=4   StackTrace:
>          at System.Configuration.BaseConfigurationRecord.FindAndEnsureFactoryRecord(String
>   configKey, Boolean& isRootDeclaredHere)
>          at System.Configuration.BaseConfigurationRecord.GetSectionRecursive(String
>   configKey, Boolean getLkg, Boolean checkPermission, Boolean
>   getRuntimeObject, Boolean requestIsHere, Object& result, Object&
>   resultRuntimeObject)
>          at System.Configuration.BaseConfigurationRecord.GetSection(String
>   configKey)
>          at System.Configuration.ClientConfigurationSystem.System.Configuration.Internal.IInternalConfigSystem.GetSection(String
>   sectionName)
>          at System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.GetSection(String sectionName)
>          at ConsoleApplication1_ConfigurationEnumerable.PathsConfigSection.GetConfig()
>   in
>   C:\Users\blackberry\Desktop\ConsoleApplication1_ConfigurationEnumerable\ConsoleApplication1_ConfigurationEnumerable\Disk.cs:line
>   63
>          at ConsoleApplication1_ConfigurationEnumerable.Program.Main(String[]
>   args) in
>   C:\Users\blackberry\Desktop\ConsoleApplication1_ConfigurationEnumerable\ConsoleApplication1_ConfigurationEnumerable\Program.cs:line
>   9
>          at System.AppDomain._nExecuteAssembly(RuntimeAssembly assembly, String[] args)
>          at System.AppDomain.ExecuteAssembly(String assemblyFile, Evidence assemblySecurity, String[] args)
>          at Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.HostProc.RunUsersAssembly()
>          at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart_Context(Object state)
>          at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext
>   executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean
>   preserveSyncCtx)
>          at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean
>   preserveSyncCtx)
>          at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
>          at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()   InnerException: System.TypeLoadException
>          HResult=-2146233054
>          Message=Could not load type 'ConsoleApplication1_ConfigurationEnumerable.PathsConfigSection' from
>   assembly 'System.Configuration, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'.
>          Source=System.Configuration
>          TypeName=ConsoleApplication1_ConfigurationEnumerable.PathsConfigSection
>          StackTrace:
>               at System.Configuration.TypeUtil.GetTypeWithReflectionPermission(IInternalConfigHost
>   host, String typeString, Boolean throwOnError)
>               at System.Configuration.RuntimeConfigurationRecord.RuntimeConfigurationFactory.Init(RuntimeConfigurationRecord
>   configRecord, FactoryRecord factoryRecord)
>               at System.Configuration.RuntimeConfigurationRecord.RuntimeConfigurationFactory.InitWithRestrictedPermissions(RuntimeConfigurationRecord
>   configRecord, FactoryRecord factoryRecord)
>               at System.Configuration.RuntimeConfigurationRecord.CreateSectionFactory(FactoryRecord
>   factoryRecord)
>               at System.Configuration.BaseConfigurationRecord.FindAndEnsureFactoryRecord(String
>   configKey, Boolean& isRootDeclaredHere)
>          InnerException:

Where is my fault ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use the [Fully Qualified Assembly Name](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k8xx4k69.aspx) when specifying the class in the `configSections` tag:

```
<configSections>
  <section name="Disk"
           type="ConsoleApplication1_ConfigurationEnumerable.PathsConfigSection, ConsoleApplication1"/>
</configSections>
```

This assumes that the name of your assembly is `ConsoleApplication1`. If you are still getting exceptions, you can determine the correct value using the the following code:

```
typeof(ConsoleApplication1_ConfigurationEnumerable.PathsConfigSection).FullName
                                                                      .ToString()
```

BTW: Your namespace is odd. Naming standard suggest that you use the dot (`.`) when separating namespace hierarchies:

```
namespace ConsoleApplication1.ConfigurationEnumerable
```

Comment: No, it isn't. Compare closely. Note the comma and `ConsoleApplication1` at the end.

Comment: That's not how SO works. Please restore your original question and post a new one for the new problem. Because that is a different problem. You are welcome to refer from your new question to this. Please make sure that you only include the relevant parts in the new question.

Comment: Ok, I follow in: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14747589/c-sharp-customized-ienumerable-in-configurationsection-ii

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use the first line (the commented-out one).  The problem is in your `<section>` element in the config file.  Follow Daniel's answer to see how that should look.