# Store array of custom class in settings file

Tags: c#, arrays, class, app-config, setting

I have one class:

```
public class CustomClass
{
    public string Columns;
    public string Filter;

    public string SourceDB;
    public string SourceTable;

    public string DestinationDB;
    public string DestinationTable;
}
```

In the user settings, I need to store an array of CustomClass. This is because I need the user ability to specifiy multiple CustomClass in the app.config file.

Comment: Look at implementing your own configuration handler, these can have multiple entries and can be customised to have multiple fields. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2tw134k3(v=vs.100).aspx

Answer (score 2):

You will have to start by creating a setting in your project settings file, let's name it `CustomClasses`. The next part is a little bit tricky, as it involves editing the XML of the *Settings.settings* file:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<SettingsFile xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/2004/01/settings" 
              CurrentProfile="(Default)" 
              GeneratedClassNamespace="ConsoleApplication1.Properties" 
              GeneratedClassName="Settings">
  <Profiles />
  <Settings>
    <Setting Name="CustomClasses" 
             GenerateDefaultValueInCode="false" 
             Type="System.Collections.Generic.List&lt;ConsoleApplication1.CustomClass&gt;" 
             Scope="User">
    </Setting>
  </Settings>
</SettingsFile>
```

If you open your *Settings.Designer.cs* file, you should have now:

```
[global::System.Configuration.UserScopedSettingAttribute()]
[global::System.Diagnostics.DebuggerNonUserCodeAttribute()]
public global::System.Collections.Generic
    .List<ConsoleApplication1.CustomClass> CustomClasses {
    get {
        return ((global::System.Collections.Generic
            .List<ConsoleApplication1.CustomClass>)(this["CustomClasses"]));
    }
    set {
        this["CustomClasses"] = value;
    }
}
```

You can save the setting in your application:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Properties.Settings.Default.CustomClasses = new List<CustomClass>() {
            new CustomClass(){Columns="columns1"},
            new CustomClass(){Columns="columns2"},
            new CustomClass(){Columns="columns3"},
            new CustomClass(){Columns="columns4"}
        };
        Properties.Settings.Default.Save();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> You can declare a CustomClassSection in App.config, and declare inside a collection of CustomClass instances. Something like:

```
<configuration>
    <configSections>
        <section name="CustomClassSection" type = "A type of class section " />
    </configSections>
</configuration>

<CustomClassSection>
    <CustomClass Columns="column1" Filter="filter1" SourceDB="sourcedb1" SourceTable="sourcetable1" DestinationDB="destdb1" DestinationTable="desttable1"/>
    <CustomClass Columns="column2" Filter="filter2" SourceDB="sourcedb2" SourceTable="sourcetable2" DestinationDB="destdb2" DestinationTable="desttable2"/>
...
</CustomClassSection>
```

> You can see how work with sections here: [How to create custom config section in app.config?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1316058/how-to-create-custom-config-section-in-app-config).