# Multiple values for a key in App.config

Tags: c#, .net, console-application, app-config

I want to write a key and multiple values in `app.config`, so that depending on the value a method is run.

**for example:**

> let the key be "syncMode" and values to be kept are "syncAll"/"syncYest"

If the value is set as syncAll, complete data sync should happen in the main program and if syncYest is set, then only yesterday's data should be sync.

How can i write this in `App.config`?

Comment: So what is the problem? Are you getting any errors?

Comment: Hi andrew.. No i didnt get any errors.. i just wanted to know if that is possible and if yes, how?

Comment: But you are saying in the comment to an answer that you tried that ("*I think thats the best way for my scenario.. i tried the same..*"). So what went wrong? What did not work when you tried? Unless you tell us it's really hard to guess.

Answer (score 1):

Based on your requirement this looks like a simple case of single name and single value.If you want "Complete data sync in the main program" set value of key syncMode = "syncAll".Otherwise if you want "yesterdays data to sync" use syncMode = "syncYest"

Answer (score 0):

You can create a custom configuration section for this. There is already a [SO Post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1316058/how-to-create-custom-config-section-in-app-config) related to this. Additionally, you can also read the official [MSDN page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228056.aspx).

Comment: thanks DHN :). I think creating a custom configuration is for more complex situations than this. thanks for sharing the post. But for now i just kept it simple in App.config

Comment: @ASN: Definitely a wise decision, since the overhead is huge. But you're welcome.