# C# - The configuration section was not found error using aspnet_regiis.exe

Tags: c#, encryption, app-config, aspnet-regiis.exe

I am trying to Encrypt sensitive connection string information inside my app.config file for a C# applicaiton that I am developing. I am using the following command from the VS command promt running as administrator:

`aspnet_regiis.exe -pef "Credentials" "C:\Users\.....\MyProjectFolderDir"`

This is the structure of my app.config file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<config>
    <configSections>
      <section name="ApplicationSettings" type="sometype"/>
      <section name="WebSettings" type="sometype"/>
      <section name="Credentials" type="sometype"/>
      <section name="SQLServerSettings" type="sometype"/>
    </configSections>

    <startup> 
        <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5.2" />
    </startup>

    <ApplicationSettings   Mode="mymode"
                           FileSearchMode="myfilemode"
                           SubtractHoursDebugging="0"/>

    <WebSettings WebApiServers=""
                    CredentialMethod="mymethod"/>

    <Credentials
                    Domain="mydomain"
                    UserName="myusername"
                    Password="mypassword"/>

    <SQLServerSettings
        ConnectionString="Server=***********"/>

  </config>
```

However, I keep getting the following error:

> Encrypting configuration section...
>   The configuration section 'Credentials' was not found.
>   Failed!

How can I get this to encrypt my section?

Comment: Have you tried using "config/Credentials"? You may have to drill down more.

Comment: Shouldn't your app.config file start with <configuration> not <config>?   So the start of the file should be   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>

Comment: Well, technically yes, but I was having issues with the schema where it was  saying something to the effect of  `"configuration is declared twice"` so I just renamed it to config.

Comment: Is this a winForms app? Because a web app should have a web.config file.

Comment: It is not winforms app, this is a console application

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So as it turns out, aspnet-regiis.exe is exclusively for web.config files. It doesn not work with app.config files unless you rename to web.config. Instead of renaming my app.config everytime I wanted to encrypt/decrypt, I ended up creating a class that would handle this each time I ran the application. Make sure you are using the following:

```
using System.Configuration;
using System.Web.Security;
```

Class:

```
internal class Crypto
{
    internal static AppSettingsSection GetEncryptedAppSettingsSection(string exeConfigName)
    {
        // Open the configuration file and retrieve 
        // the connectionStrings section.
        System.Configuration.Configuration config = ConfigurationManager.
            OpenExeConfiguration(exeConfigName);

        AppSettingsSection section =
                config.GetSection("appSettings")
                as AppSettingsSection;

        EncryptConfigSection(config, section);
        return section;
    }

    internal static ConnectionStringsSection GetEncryptedConnectionStringsSection(string exeConfigName)
    {
        // Open the configuration file and retrieve 
        // the connectionStrings section.
        System.Configuration.Configuration config = ConfigurationManager.
            OpenExeConfiguration(exeConfigName);

        ConnectionStringsSection section =
                config.GetSection("connectionStrings")
                as ConnectionStringsSection;

        EncryptConfigSection(config, section);
        return section;
    }

    internal static void EncryptConfigSection(System.Configuration.Configuration config, ConfigurationSection section)
    {
        //Ensure config sections are always encrypted
        if (!section.SectionInformation.IsProtected)
        {
            // Encrypt the section.
            section.SectionInformation.ProtectSection("DataProtectionConfigurationProvider");
            // Save the current configuration.
            config.Save();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your config file should start with `<configuration>` element and not `<config>`. Since it's `<config>` `aspnet_regiis.exe` thinning `Credentials` as nested element and thus the error. With your current config file the command should be

```
aspnet_regiis.exe -pef "config\Credentials" "C:\Users\.....\MyProjectFolderDir"
```

Comment: I've tried this, and it still does not work. Can someone try on their machine?

Comment: C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727>aspnet_regiis.exe -pef "config/Credentials" "C:\Users\Me\Desktop"
Encrypting configuration section...
The configuration section 'config/Credentials' was not found.
Failed!

Answer (score 0):

First of all here's an answer that you can learn from about custom configuration section [How to create custom config section in app.config?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1316058/how-to-create-custom-config-section-in-app-config) and here is an example from msdn https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2tw134k3.aspx

Second, the type usually refer to a real model so you should enter the namespace and the class that you created to model the type of configuration you would like to use like so:

```
 <configuration>
 <configSections>
  <section name="sampleSection"
           type="System.Configuration.SingleTagSectionHandler" />
</configSections>
<sampleSection setting1="Value1" setting2="value two" 
              setting3="third value" />
</configuration>
```

Hope it helps